# How to read .mp3 file uploaded from local folder to just_audio app on Flutter web?

Tags: just-audio, is-uploaded-file

I want to display name, author, artists,... information of music files (mostly mp3) on just_audio widget but failed to achieve it.

I display the music app on Flutter web, can anybody recommend me methods to obtain this goal? Thank you.